# facebook login on asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-oauth

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC 4 project and I want to improve it by adding facebook authentication option. My issue is to log in the user after he/she successfully logged to facebook and is redirected to my website.

I have the standard AccountController with the ExternalLoginCallback method:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }

        if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // If the current user is logged in add the new account
            OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
            string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
            ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new RegisterExternalLoginModel { UserName = result.UserName, ExternalLoginData = loginData });
        }
    }
```

When this code runs, if the user is already registered to my website and uses facebook for login only I want to log him/her in and redirect to home page. If the user is a new one, I want to create an account using the email I get from facebook - for this I will redirect the user to "Register page".

My issue is, at this moment, to log in an existing user. The way I register users in my website is by saving the email as UserName (should be unique) and a password respectively. When the user login using facebook I get the user's email and I want to use this email to log the user.

Now back to code:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false)
```

from the above method always returns false - even if the user is already registered (throw normal website registration form).

**What is the correct way to handle this? How do I log in a user using facebook (and more external auth services in the future)?**